# ubuntu 18.04.04 sound mixer bug

Tags: 18.04, sound, firefox, pulseaudio, bug-reporting

There is a bug in ubuntu 18.04 default sound mixer,

Setup: I have two media streams playing mozilla has my songs and on chrome i have lectures or youtube or other media playing, i have sunk the volume of the mozilla from the settings

bug: whenever the songs change the slider of mozilla is reset to full in settings so there is blast of sound all of a sudden

[image of my sound mixer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XfVM.png)

Comment: If it's a bug, it should be reported on a bug tracking site such as launchpad (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) and not a user support site such as this one.  Are you trying to report a bug (as you appear to have described), or are actually seeking support?

Comment: @guiverc I am seeking support for my problem. thank you for asking, can you help?